# Send datas to an ASP.NET website using Jsoup in Android

Tags: android, html, asp.net, json, jsoup

I am trying to build an app which parse the website then it can send datas back to the server which generates the output .

The site uses ASP.NET  it is : 
On the left side you can see selectors. The third selector's value depends on the second selector's value. So I have to send back the second selector value somehow to the server.

I could parse the first and second selector's value to my Spinners. But I am Stuck at the third (don't know how to send back the second spinner's value) .

Here is my code below (Gets the datas from the second selector and put to Spinner, it works fine ) :

```
 Elements szovetseg = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "d_szervezet").get(0).children();

 for (int i = 0; i < szovetseg.size(); i++) {
                String a = "";
                String[] parts = szovetseg.get(i).toString().split(">");

                a = parts[1];

                String[] parts2 = a.split("<");
                a = parts2[0];

                Szovetsegek.add(a);

            }
```

Then the second Spinner gets the value by adapter from Szovetsegek List.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the HTML you are trying to parse? There is probably an easier way using css selectors.